# How to insert a large image into an SQL database

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

If I insert a small image, for example 1-2 kb, then it is successful, if I select an image of 70 kb or any other large one, then I always have an error.
I have tried both the stored procedure and directly pass an array of bytes - error.

> Exception System.Data.SqlClient.SQLException: "A transport layer error occurred while receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout is exceeded.)"

Everything is fine with SQL Server itself, images are loaded successfully through WinForms, there are no problems.

Button:

```
<RadzenUpload Accept="image/*" ChooseText="Select..." Url=@($"api/upload/single/{clientid}/1") Progress="@((args) => OnProgress(args, "Loading ..."))" />
```

Controller and void:

```
[HttpPost("single/{id}/{photoid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult>  Single(IFormFile file, string id,string photoid)
    {
        try
        {
            IVZBlazor.Iservice.IPhotoService serv;

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string rootpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
            string path = rootpath + "\\Uploads";
            using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
            long length = file.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
            fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(stream);

            }
           await Save(bytes, id);
            return StatusCode(200);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private DynamicParameters SetParameter(byte[] oPhoto)
    {
        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@photo", oPhoto);
        return parameters;
    }
    public async Task<int> Save(byte[] photo, string clientid)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Startup.ConnectSQL))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            var sqlStatement = @"UPDATE [dbo].[photo] SET [image1] =@photo WHERE [personid] ='" + clientid + "'";
            int res = await connection.ExecuteAsync(sqlStatement, SetParameter(photo));
            return res;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm confused by the SQL statement; you pass a `Photo` object, and set `[image1]` to `@photo`. Does `SetParameter` set `@photo` to an array of bytes? I would think this would be better if you did it asynchronously, via `Task<IActionResult>` and the various *Async methods in .NET Core's System.IO namespace. Also, I'm not sure why you're not using a parameter for `ClientId` just as you are for `photo`...

Comment: I rewrote it, I was just doing something and the code became crooked. But it doesn't change anything, everything works only if you upload a small image.

Comment: It changes the question, certainly. Passing in an object to a parameter expecting a byte array would throw an exception, and not the one you posted. Programming requires attention to details -- good programmers pay attention to those details. In any case, it sounds like an issue with the connection between the web server and the SQL Server. Perhaps high latency or you should try using a named pipes provider instead of TCP.

Comment: It may be the problem caused by the network，you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466818/execution-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elaps.html).

Comment: Your code is quite confused. Search how to convert IFormFile to byte array. You don't need to use a temporary file.

Comment: You may have to chunk it into 4k blocks....

Comment: Brian, A good idea, but I do not know how to implement it